# why is rendering images using itext is too slow on Android 6.0 and works fine with Android 7.0?

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext, itext7

Note  i have used the following code in another activity for creating pdfs and it s speed was good   on Android 6.0 and 7.0

the more images in the pdf the slower the process 
2 pages took 28 seconds to be converted and saved to a pdf on Android 6
while 2 pages took 2 seconds on android 7

i have tried  2 versions of itext for rendering pdf images to a pdf using those 2 codes

first code slowing down on :
 Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(photoFile.getPath())); 
and the second code on : 
 image1 = Image.getInstance(photoFile.getPath());

Maybe it is a memory problem around 100 MB are allocated shows the monitor still i dont know how to fix it

```
Code 1 :
 @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... args) {


            Document document = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);

      PdfWriter writer = null;
                try {
                    File pdffile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + pdfname);
                    String filePath = pdffile.getPath();
                    writer = new PdfWriter(filePath);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
                Document document = new Document(pdf);
                for (int z = 0; z < pagecount; z++) {
                    File photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Faxphoto" + z + ".png");


                    try {
                        Image img = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(photoFile.getPath()));
                        img.scaleToFit(PageSize.LEGAL.getWidth(), PageSize.LEGAL.getHeight());




                        document.add(img);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //Close document
                }
                document.close();  


            return null;
        }


      Code 2 :

         @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Object... args) {


                    Document document = new Document(PageSize.LEGAL, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);


                    try {

                        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                                new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + pdfname));
                    } catch (DocumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    document.open();
                    for (int z = 0; z < pagecount; z++) {
                        File photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Faxphoto" + z + ".png");
                        Image image1 = null;

                        try {Log.e("Started processs","1");
                            image1 = Image.getInstance(photoFile.getPath());
                        } catch (BadElementException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        try {

                            image1.scaleToFit(PageSize.LEGAL.getWidth(), PageSize.LEGAL.getHeight());
                            image1.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
                            document.add(image1);
                            document.newPage();
                            Log.e("Finished processs","2");

                        } catch (DocumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }


                    }
                    document.close();


                    return null;
                }
```

Comment: Looks like I/O slowdown to me, both those methods read an file on disk/local memory and create the image data in memory. Could also be a memory problem if the images are particularly large, since you have to keep them in memory at least until the page they've been added to is flushed.

Comment: the images size was too big which was causing a problem thanks @Samuel Huylebroeck